# SQL in R: subquery with numerical conditions on a row level

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I am learning sql in R.
I have a database with City Names and City Longitude data. I want to select all cities that are closer than 0.2 longitude away from the longitude half circle between Paris and Berlin.

I am basically trying to do:
"Select all cities and longitudes where the longitudes are

1. between Berlin and (Berlin + 0.2)
   AND
2. between Paris and (Paris - 0.2)"

```
sql7 = "SELECT Name, Longitude FROM city
WHERE Longitude IN (SELECT Name, Longitude FROM city WHERE Longitude BETWEEN (SELECT Longitude FROM city WHERE NAME LIKE 'Berlin') 
AND 
(SELECT Longitude FROM city wHERE Name LIKE 'Berlin') + 0.2) 
AND
SELECT Name, Longitude FROM city
WHERE Longitude IN (SELECT Name, Longitude FROM city WHERE Longitude BETWEEN (SELECT Longitude FROM city WHERE NAME LIKE 'Paris') 
AND 
(SELECT Longitude FROM city wHERE Name LIKE 'Paris') - 0.2)"
result7 = dbSendQuery(con, sql7)
df7 = dbFetch(result7)
df7
```

I think I need to do it with subqueries, but this is not working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to test without data, but I think you need "name" from inner select, instead of "name, longitude":

```sql
SELECT name,
       longitude
FROM city
WHERE name IN
    (SELECT name
     FROM city
     WHERE longitude BETWEEN
         (SELECT longitude
          FROM city
          WHERE name LIKE 'Berlin') AND
         (SELECT longitude
          FROM city
          WHERE name LIKE 'Berlin') + 0.2)
  AND name IN
  SELECT name
  FROM city WHERE longitude IN
    (SELECT name,
            longitude
     FROM city
     WHERE longitude BETWEEN
         (SELECT longitude
          FROM city
          WHERE name LIKE 'Paris') AND
         (SELECT longitude
          FROM city
          WHERE name LIKE 'Paris') - 0.2)
```

Tip: format your code for readability: https://sqlformat.org/